# jOOQ to select distinct array aggregate in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I am trying to get jOOQ to emit this (without much luck):

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT my_field) FROM ...
```

I ended up using a plain-SQL field.

Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

If not, would it make sense to add a `.distinct()` method to `Field` that can be used with any aggregate function? Or a `DSL.distinct(Field)` that creates a Field, rather than a SelectStep - not sure if that makes a difference.

This currently seems to be accomplished by creating separate DSL methods for each aggregate: `countDistinct`, `groupConcatDistinct`, `min/max/sum/avgDistinct`, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a `DSL.arrayAggDistinct()` function available from jOOQ 3.10 onwards:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6281

Until then, simply use the [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) as a workaround:

```java
public static <T> Field<T[]> arrayAggDistinct(Field<T> myField) {
    return DSL.field("array_agg(distinct {0})", myField.getArrayDataType(), myField);
}
```